# Is there a way to select individual cells?

Tags: c#, datagrid, .net-micro-framework

I am working on a project in C# on the .net micro framework, using the [GHI Glide graphical library](https://www.ghielectronics.com/glide). I need to navigate a [DataGrid](https://www.ghielectronics.com/downloads/man/Library_Documentation_v4.3/html/T_GHI_Glide_UI_DataGrid.htm) through the use of directional keys and a numeric keypad (and NO touchscreen). There is an enter button which I am using to activate what I call "Edit DataGrid Mode", where I call the following on the DataGrid myGrid (which selects row 10, for example, and colors it yellow): `myGrid.SelectedIndex = 10;`

Problem is, I would like to be able to enter into a "Edit Cell Mode" when I click the enter button again, but in the [DataGrid class](https://www.ghielectronics.com/downloads/man/Library_Documentation_v4.3/html/T_GHI_Glide_UI_DataGrid.htm), there doesn't seem to be any way to show a cell is selected. I thought about using a popup window that would get the data from the cell and then proceed from there, but I would rather avoid popups in favor of a more streamlined approach.

Am I missing something about how I could trigger touch events to make a cell select? Or should I just go the hardcore route and use something similar to `window.Graphics.DrawTextInRect(...);` to make a text rectangle appear over the cell I am editing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, but I found that the GHI Glide graphical library for .net micro framework does not have this capability, and other ways of inputting data must be used (sorry for the confusion, there wasn't a tag for Glide). I ended up using a TextBox component to serve as a background and adding other components on top of it, setting the text of those components as I retrieved data from the table.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `selection unit` property of the Datagrid. `Selection Mode` would be the alternative to your problem if selection unit is already on cell.